# How do I transfer a folder from my internet storage directory to a private directory in pydroid 3

Tags: pydroid

I tried ls /storage I tried cd /storage/emulated/0 nothing chatgpt can't can you
I tried ls /storage I tried cd /storage/emulated/0 nothing chatgpt can't can you I can't move With what I am creating till I do this help please

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal in Pydroid and type:

cd

pwd

You should see this directory "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/app_HOME"

Now type:
mv "path to your folder" .

Example

mv /sdcard/xsu .

Then you can type ls to see it.